# Maven override properties from command line does for child modules cross reference

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3, pom.xml

I have a multi module maven project that has a parent pom and two children child1 and child2. Each of child1 and child 2 as two child modules each as

Child1 -> Child 11,Child12 
Child2 -> Child 21,Child22.

Child 12 has a dependency over child 21 with version as ${my.version}.
Child 22 has dependency over child 12 with version as ${my.version}.

The top most parent pom has a default property as 1.0.0 and all children are version-ed with ${my.version}.

Now If I run "mvn clean install -Dmy.version=1.0.2", I get a failure in module Child 22 that it is unable to locate dependency Child 21 with version 1.0.0. I guess something is not being done correctly here and the property my.version is not 100% overridden by command line when there are cross module dependencies across children.

It works correctly if I remove 1.0.0 from top most pom.xml and run command mvn clean install -Dmy.version-1.0.2.

I have a sample project created to prove this in case required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to have diferent versions within the same parent. Try using the same version for all (sub)modules and reference with ${project.version}. This keeps stable even if you change the version.

To change the version of all you modules use the maven-version-plugin or the maven-release-plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do want all modules and sub modules  to have the same version referenced by my.version property. Only when -Dmy.version is not provided through command line all modules to be build with default my.version which is 1.0.0.  If i override my.version with 1.0.2 the i would want all modules to be 1.0.2 versioned